# Please explain RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a class

```
public class Client extends RestTemplate
// org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

What is RestTemplate used for?

Comment: Did you have look at the [RestTemplate JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) already?

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume you understand the concept of templating in spring. (its based on a design patten with the same name). RestTemplate is a template used to make HTTP Rest Calls (REST Client).

If you want to  make a HTTP Call, you need to create a HttpClient, pass  request and (or) form parameters, setup accept headers and perform unmarshalling of response, all by yourself, Spring Rest Templates, tries to take the pain away by abstracting all these details from you.

http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly. I'm currently at the second guide of Spring Boot's docs, and I didn't need to override any template methods in the `RestTemplate` class to use the methods. I used a `RestTemplateBuilder` though, which perhabs took care of overriding the appropriate methods.