# how to access data from another web application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, path, context.xml

I have two application name "appserver" and "ftpserver" both on same tomcat server. like this: 
appserver: "http://myapplication.org/appserver"
ftpserver: "http://myapplication.org/ftpserver"

appserver is the main application of my project and I want to "upload" & "get"  some files to/from ftpserver. so how do i can get the url/path of the ftpserver in Java, JSP, & java script??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, you can go with RestTemplete for this case.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721279/please-explain-resttemplate)